# Regex on SQL using Java

Tags: java, sql, regex

All I have are SQL Insert statements. I want to do is caputre from the `Insert` to the end semicolon. Such as:

`Insert blah INTO blah VAULES(blah);`

I need to capture all of these.

I am using this `^([^;]*)` as my regex.

This is my Java code:

```
private String processFile(String data) {
    StringBuilder retVal = new StringBuilder();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String match = matcher.group(1);
        match = match.replaceAll("\n", "");
        retVal.append(match).append(";\n");
    }
    return retVal.toString();
}
```

But it seems to only capture the first occurrence. How can I capture all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression contains start of string matcher `^` which can match only once.

If you want to match multiple entries replace start of string matcher with something that repeats (like `Insert` keyword):

`Insert([^;]*)`

Comment: Cool, that did it. Thanks